# MySQL: Converting VARCHAR to DECIMAL and find between range

Tags: mysql

I have some data like this in a column

```
H1.1
H1.2
H1.3
H1.10
H50.1
H50.5
H55.5
```

I want to search between #1.10 to #50.1.  I have tried a query like this but I am not getting the desired result.

```
SELECT p_code FROM table 
WHERE CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(`code`,'H',''), '.', 1),SIGNED INTEGER) between CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1.1', '.', 1),SIGNED INTEGER) 
AND CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1.99', '.', 1),SIGNED INTEGER) 
AND CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(`code`,'H',''), '.', 1),SIGNED INTEGER) 
between CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1.1', '.', -1),SIGNED INTEGER) 
AND CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1.99', '.', -1),SIGNED INTEGER) 
AND CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(`code`,'H',''), '.', 1),SIGNED INTEGER)>=CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1.1', '.', 1),SIGNED INTEGER) 
AND CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(`code`,'H',''), '.', 1),SIGNED INTEGER)<=CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1.99', '.', 1),SIGNED INTEGER)
AND CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(`code`,'H',''), '.', -1),SIGNED INTEGER)>=CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1.1', '.', -1),SIGNED INTEGER) 
AND CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(`code`,'H',''), '.', -1),SIGNED INTEGER)<=CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1.99', '.', -1),SIGNED INTEGER)
ORDER BY LENGTH(`code`)  desc ,`code` desc
```

I have also tried this:

```
(CONVERT(REPLACE(`code`,'H',''),DECIMAL(5,3)) BETWEEN CONVERT('1.1',DECIMAL(5,3))
AND CONVERT('1.99',DECIMAL(5,3)))
```

Comment: Is 1.3 "between" 1.10 and 50.1?  Or not?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a temporary table :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (
    code decimal(5,3)
);

INSERT INTO temp_table (code)
SELECT CONVERT(REPLACE(`code`,'H',''), DECIMAL(5,3))
FROM `table`;
SELECT code FROM temp_table WHERE code BETWEEN 1.10 AND 50.1;
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer...let me check if it works

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (
    code decimal(5,3)
);

INSERT INTO temp_table (code)
SELECT CONVERT(REPLACE(`code`,'H',''), DECIMAL(5,3))
FROM `table`;
SELECT code FROM temp_table WHERE code BETWEEN 1.1 AND 1.10; showing only 1.10 but result must be 1.1,1.2,1.3